# The operator or administrator has refused the request task scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I have scheduled a C# console application in Task Scheduler of Windows 2012 R2. Application will run when executed it manually or Right click on scheduled task and click on **Run**, but it is failed when triggered by Task Scheduler with below error.

> The operator or administrator has refused the request(0x800710E0)

I have followed below steps also after Google search

1. Selected "**Run whether user logged in or not**"
2. Unchecked "**Start the task only if the computer is on AC power**"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Error occurred due to folder permission, I was creating CSV from my application, which was required folder permission to be granted. After giving **Full Control** to the folder error got resolved.

Answer (score 58):

In my case, the error message "*The operator or administrator has refused the request*" meant that a **previous instance of the task has still been running** and the task was configured to not start a new instance if it's already running (the default configuration), so the Task Scheduler refused to start a new instance when the task was triggered.

You can find that option in a select box on the task's *Settings* tab, under the caption "*If the task is already running, then the following rule applies*". The default value is "*Do not start a new instance*".

[image: Task settings dialog]

But that error message is pretty confusing. From the other answers, you may see that it may mean many completely distinct errors. As is usual in Microsoft's products.

### Tip

It's helpful to check the *History* tab of a task. That's where I have found out what's actually going on. There was an event "*Launch request ignored, instance already running*".

Answer (score 30):

**In my case, I had to redo the permissions on the task.** Somehow it had lost the domain portion of the username. Instead of `DOMAIN\joeuser' it was just 'joeuser'. After a reset, it worked correctly as it had for the previous year.

[image]

Comment: This is normal behavior on some systems. After reopening the task or after a reboot it often is the case that the domain name no longer will appear as shown, meaning that FBC-2007 will be removed from the textbox on that properties dialog. This doesn't mean that it's gone--it just isn't displayed anymore--only the user name component is shown. This happens consistently on my Windows 10 Enterprise Task Scheduler.

Comment: @Jazimov The point of my answer is simple: "In my case, I had to redo the permissions on the task."

Comment: No, it wasn't simple: You highlighted the domain name as if to show everyone reading this thread that the domain name should appear as you deliberately highlighted it. My point is that a missing domain is a normal part of how this dialog works. I don't agree with that "normalcy"--I think it should always show the domain/username format. Anyone reading what you wrote would likely be confused, so I chimed in to clarify.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem with a scheduled task I had setup. The username had lost the domain name part, or was somehow originally setup without it and worked okay for awhile.

Comment: A previously working task can suffer this error after you change your password. The solution is to redo the permissions, as above (don't tick "do not store password")

Answer (score 16):

In my case, having a job setup with **Task Scheduler** as written about in the ["Prevent a Task Scheduler Task from Executing on Setting Updates"](https://superuser.com/questions/1330690/updating-a-scheduled-task-with-repeat-every-x-hours-causes-it-to-be-triggered/1330695#1330695), I had a job setup to run every "X" minutes for a period of indefinitely.

[image]

Upon seeing the dreaded "*The operator or administrator has refused the request*" for the **Last Run Result**, I looked over the **History** tab and see detail indicating that is "*missed its schedule*".

[image]

[image]

### The Solution

From the **Settings** tab of the job properties, I simply checked the option "**Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed**", and problem resolved; although, I did have to type in the credential again as well.

[image]

**Note:** This started occurring once a server was moved from a redundant backup server once hardware repair was completed back to the original hardware. The OS was Server 2012 R2 and the OS was moved to other hardware while repair was done on the production server but I didn't notice this there—maybe an oversight there though—not sure.

Answer (score 5):

I know that @Sushmit-Patil found a solution, but I wanted to add a solution to my similar problem:

It turns out a prior process never exited (it was hanging around in memory because of a defect I had in my code). By default, Windows Task Scheduler won't run the process again if it's already running.

In addition to fixing the defect, in Task Scheduler, under the Settings tab, I set *If the task is already running, then the following rule applies:* to **Run a new instance in parallel**

[image: Task Scheduler Run a new instance in parallel][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReRXO.png)

Answer (score 3):

For me, the solution was to check `Run with highest privileges` in the properties.

Answer (score 3):

In my case my task launches a PowerShell script--and it produced the "The operator or administrator has refused the request (0x800710E0)" error message as seen in the Task Scheduler's task-entry grid. My user name was correct, but when I dropped to a command prompt and simulated the task by running the PowerShell against my .ps1 file, **I saw an Avast prompt that flagged my script as suspicious** and wasn't allowing it to run. I created an Avast exception and now the task runs without any issue.

Answer (score 3):

After turning on history I also had the error "Missed task start rejected: Task Scheduler did not launch task as it missed its schedule." but I didn't want the task to start when I woke up the computer, I wanted to figure out **why the computer didn't wake up**.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47782537/771768) helped me out -- by default Windows was waking for "Important Wake Timers Only" (system updates, but not my scheduled task).

In the setting Power Options > Edit Plan Settings > Change advanced power settings > Sleep > Allow wake timer change the option to "Enabled" and then your computer will wake up to run the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this from "settings". Probably earlier instance was already running and launching a new instance failed.

[image: Option in Settings]

Comment: For some case it will work, in my case earlier instance was executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error message *"The operator or administrator has refused the request"* appeared because the computer was in stand-by at the scheduled time (and the options "Wake the computer to run this task" and "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start was missed" were unchecked).

I had previously chosen "Enable All Tasks History" and a more useful error message appeared in the History tab: *"Missed task start rejected: Task Scheduler did not launch task  as it missed its schedule. Consider using the configuration option to start the task when available, if schedule is missed."*

Answer (score 1):

I have found what I believe to be a bizarre bug in Windows Server 2016 scheduler and maybe other Windows Server versions that produces the OP's error (and a workaround):

Here are the conditions:

1. You're using the "Monthly" option trigger in your task (I currently have all months selected and just a couple days chosen, e.g. 1st and 15th)
2. You have the "Synchronize across time zones" selected.

This was originally an issue I found back in November 2020 when my tasks were running twice all of a sudden after the DST time change (and this was a widely reported bug, but not an obvious solution). I never would have known, except that users started receiving duplicate emails from one of my tasks. In the history you would simply see the task running twice at what appeared to be exactly the same time. It worked fine before the time change. I forget all the troubleshooting I did then, but my end theory was that it was somehow confusing the time after the time change. The work around was to set the option "Synchronize across time zones" and all seemed well...

Fast forward to March when the DST time just changed back again and now I get every time the tasks with the Monthly option runs:

> The operator or administrator has refused the request

The History tab on the task is also blank. If you change options and save, the History tab starts logging again and then sometimes stops if the task errors again. Weird.

One work around is to simply turn off the "Synchronize across time zones" option (tested). However, I don't recommend that option as I assume you'll have the duplicate running task issue again when the DST time changes again in November.

The one time I got an error to show in the History tab it stated:

> Task Scheduler did not launch task "\EmailCampaign" as it missed its
> schedule. Consider using the configuration option to start the task
> when available, if schedule is missed.

Therefore, I went and set that option to start the task if the schedule is missed and all seems well. I figured I'd see the original error and then subsequently the task running, but no error any more either. It all just works.

I know this solution was reported above, but that's because most people's computers were asleep or something to that effect. My issue is on a production internet facing server that doesn't go to sleep, hibernate or anything related and only happens with specific conditions related to the Monthly trigger option. All my others tens of scheduled tasks work flawless.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Powershell script to do a task.  I was getting this error and landed here (as well as other lower ranked search results).  The task would run manually and the first time it was triggered, but not on repeat even though I had it set up to end the task if it took longer than a minute.
My problem was caused by not providing an exit code in my powershell script.  Task scheduler simply did not know the task had finished and would consider it still running.  I could have simply allowed the next instance of the task to be started if the previous was not finished, but using the exit code is the 'right way'.
So I simply added a new line on the end of my PS1 --

```
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

This topic is old but I had the same problem on windows server 2016.
My task executes a BAT script that zip a folder and upload on an external backup.

The task never ended because there was a "pause" at the end of my script. And my task was configured with "Dot not start a new instance" settings.

I solved my problem by removing the "pause". I don't know if it will be useful..